# Appropriate Class Usage? - Python

Tags: python, class, oop, object, performance

So, I've been using a simple paradigm for my command line application. One base class called "Command" is inherited multiple times so I can use the child classes to do my dirty work in a while loop. This while loop asked for a command and ran that input through a dictionary to point to the correct class and call Command().run() (The classes needed to be initialized for several unimportant reasons). It looks something like this:

```
class Command(object):
    #Some of these parent variables where used as constants and
    #redefined in the global scope
    dir = ""
    password = ""
    target = ""
    status_msg = "only for child classes"

    def __init__(self):
        self.names = [self.__class__.__name__.lower()]

    def run(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("There has to be code for the program to run!")


class End(Command):
    status_msg = "Closing program and resources ..."

    def __init__(self):
        Command.__init__(self)
        names = [
            "exit", "close", "quit"
        ]
        self.names.extend(names)

    def run(self):
        #Do checks and close resources?
        sys.exit()

while True:
    command = input("What will you be doing with said folder? ")
    try:
        cmd = commands[strip(command.lower())]()  #  Strip is defined elsewhere in the code
        print("\n", cmd.status_msg, "\n")
        cmd.run()
    except Exception as __e:
        print("Error: \n    " + str(__e))
        print("Perhaps you misspelled something? Please try again \n")
```

and other classes would overwrite the run commands and the class variables.

I've been wondering whether or not this is a Pythonic use of classes, and whether or not is efficient. In the end this amounts to two questions.

Is this a pythonic use of classes?
Is this the most efficient way to code something like this?

Any help is welcome; I'm not a coding pro, but I always like to learn something new about one of my favorite coding languages! (I am willing to edit this post if you guys think the question is worded incorrectly, because I'm not completely confident it will make sense to *everybody*.)

Comment: Might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Iguananaut you may be right :/. I was not paying attention because this is the site I come to for all my coding problems. I had to write this question because I haven't seen anything like it (^-^)\ - and it's my first question! I think I'll leave it up a bit longer before I try and move it.

Comment: no problem; it's not a bad question. Just rather open-ended and particular to your code.  If you do end up moving it I'll try to answer over there.

Comment: @Iguananaut thank you! I guess it is kinda open-ended, and particular to me... perhaps people will springboard off of my way of handling command line applications. I'll try to remember to post this question over on Code Review for you.

Comment: One suggestion would be to raise `NotImplementedError` in your abstract base `Command` class where you require children to override something.

Comment: @roippi Wow, I've never heard of that error. Shows how much I know :D. Thank you, I'll add it to my code right now!

Comment: This pattern is called the [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). It is widely used and accepted as a good solution for this type of reoccurring problem.

Comment: @clcto Huh. That's a lot of reading, but at least I'm not alone! I'm glad I came up with this structure all on my own though. Thanks for the info!